# Mappings of triangular regions by complex variables

Tags: complex-analysis

This is Problem #30 (chapter 8) in Schaum's outline of Complex Variables :

We have a triangle with vertices at points at $i$, $1-i$, and $1+i$.
We want to sketch the region of the $w$ plane into which the interior of the triangle is mapped under the transformations

A. $w=z^2$

B. $w=iz^2 +(2-i)z$

C. $w=z+\frac{1}{z}$

Here is the problems I am facing and what I have done:

In part A, I can see that line $x=1$ maps into $u=1-\frac{v^2}{4}$, and line $y=1$ maps into $u=\frac{v^2}{4} -1$. However, line $y=-2x +1$ maps into $u= -3x^2+4x-1$, $v=-4x^2+2x$, but now my problem is how to find a relation between $u$ and $v$. I do not how this can be done.

In Part B, I can see that line $x=1$ is mapped into $v= -u^2+2u$ , but line $y=1$ maps into $v=x^2-x+1$, $u=1$ and again I cannot find a relation between $u$ and $v$.

Also line $y=-2x+1$ maps into $u=4x^2 -2x +1$ , $v=-3x^2-x+1$, and again I cannot find a relation between $u$ and $v$.

In part C, line $x=1$ is mapped to $u=1+ \frac{1}{1+y^2}$ , $v=y\left(1- \frac{1}{1+y^2}\right)$ and I cannot find a relation between $u$ and $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case **A** you have parametric form of three sides for the triangle as following:
\begin{cases}
i\to 1+i&t+i~~,0\leq t\leq1&\to&w=t^2-1+2it\\
1+i\to1-i&1-i(2t-1)~~,0\leq t\leq1&\to&w=4t(1-t)-2i(2t-1)\\
1-i\to i&1-t+i(2t-1)~~,0\leq t\leq1&\to&w=-3t^2+2t-2i(2t^2-3t+1)
\end{cases}
I draw this area by *Mathematica* code :

> ParametricPlot[{{t^2-1,2t},{4t(1-t),-2(2t-1)},{2t-3t^2,-2(2t^2-3t+1)}},{t,0,1}]

made this
[image: area]